# Is it ok to use ansible for deployement of apps instead of make files

Tags: makefile, ansible

I have recently started using `ansible` for configuration management of linux servers.

My habbit is that if I learn one tool then I try to use it as much as possible.

Initially for my php web apps I had a long `Makefile` which used to download, install packages , make php.ini file chnages , extract zip files , copy files between folders etc to deploy my application in as automated way.

Now, I am thinking of converting that `Makefile` deployment to `Ansible` because then I can arrange the separate `yml` file for separate areas rather than one big `makefile` for the whole project.

I want to know that is it good idea to use ansible for that or `Makefile` will be good for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, Ansible is great for that.  You can separate all your different steps into different [playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks.html) that are identified by yaml files.

You can define common [tasks](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html#task-include-files-and-encouraging-reuse) and then include them in your specific playbooks.

You can also make use of Ansible roles to create complete set of playbooks depending on the role of the server.  For example, one set servers' role could be `webservers` and another set of servers' role could be `databases`.

You can find more info on roles here: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html

There are's also a few modules on the web out there that you can also use to get you started and you can also use [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) to import roles.

Of course, you can accomplish the same by breaking down your `Makefile` but maybe you want to learn a new tool.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The onlyhting i could not find is , for example i am downloading zip file from internet, how can check not to download file if zip file is already there

Comment: thanks rico , i ahve asked new questin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469880/how-can-i-check-the-file-existence-in-ansible