# How can I check if file has been downloaded in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am downloading the file with `wget` from ansible.

```
  - name: Download Solr
    shell: wget http://mirror.mel.bkb.net.au/pub/apache/lucene/solr/4.7.0/solr-4.7.0.zip
      args:
        chdir: {{project_root}}/solr
```

but I only want to do that if zip file does not exist in that location. Currently the system is downloading it every time.

Comment: Why nobody adviced `args: {creates: filename}`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Unless you have a reason to use `wget` why not use `get_url` module. It will check if the file needs to be downloaded.

```
---
- hosts        : all
  gather_facts : no
  tasks:
   - get_url:
       url="http://mirror.mel.bkb.net.au/pub/apache/lucene/solr/4.7.0/solr-4.7.0.zip"
       dest="{{project_root}}/solr-4.7.0.zip"
```

**NOTE:** If you put the directory and not the full path in the `dest` ansible will still download the file to a temporary dir but do an md5 check to decide whether to copy to the dest dir.

And if you need to save state of download you can use:

```
---
- hosts        : all
  gather_facts : no
  tasks:
   - get_url:
       url="http://mirror.mel.bkb.net.au/pub/apache/lucene/solr/4.7.0/solr-4.7.0.zip"
       dest="{{project_root}}/solr-4.7.0.zip"
     register: get_solr

   - debug: 
       msg="solr was downloaded"
     when: get_solr|changed
```

Comment: While this is answer is certainly the best approach for downloading a file, the question asked "How can i check the file existence in ansible", not "How can I download a file in ansible". Good job reading between the lines for what the OP actually wanted, but technically this does not answer the question.

Comment: The question as quoted "I only want to do that if zip file does not exist in that location" that code does that. And the second task the debug, if you look at the **when** it will only be executed if file does not exist and was downloaded.

Comment: DomaNitro: @BenWhaley is correct in saying that you did not answer the question. Don't think in terms of single guy who asked a question once, think in terms of millions of people who will google it up forever. Your answer will just waste their time. Bottom line: question starter should not have accepted your answer, so it wasn't first in row.

Comment: @pfalcon Thank you for the comments but I disagree the person who asked the question was satisfied he asked the question in certain contexts. So adding another layer of check after get_url is redundant. if you want to check for file existence generically ask the question again or check http://docs.ansible.com/file_module.html

Comment: @DomaNitro, thanks for taking suggestion positively. The "issue" is that question is #2 in google output for "ansible check file existence", so asking another question with the same title won't help other people for a long time (and likely will be closed as dup). Anyway, the most productive thing I can do is post another answer with up to date way to do it.

Comment: I have a different problem here. The get_url takes time even if the files are already downloaded, so I can only guess that the check isn't working properly by default.

Comment: Solved, I now use destination path of the file, not just directory.

Answer (score 54):

Note: this answer covers general question of "How can i check the file existence in ansible", not a specific case of downloading file.

The problems with the previous answers using "command" or "shell" actions is that they won't work in --check mode. Actually, first action will be skipped, and next will error out on "when: solr_exists.rc != 0" condition (due to variable not being defined).

Since Ansible 1.3, there's more direct way to check for file existance - using "stat" module. It of course also works well as "local_action" to check a local file existence:

```
- local_action: stat path={{secrets_dir}}/secrets.yml
  register: secrets_exist

- fail: msg="Production credentials not found"
  when: secrets_exist.stat.exists == False
```

Comment: I believe local_action is deprecated and you can just use `stat: path={{secrets_dir}}/secrets.yml` directly.  This answered the question I was here for, so thanks.  Imo the object stat registers could use more documentation (or I could inspect it with ipython). /lazyme

Answer (score 20):

Many modules are already aware of the result and will be skipped if its already there, like `file` or `geturl`. Others like `command` have a `creates` option, which will skip this command if that file already exists (or doesn't exist, if you use the `removes` option).

So you should first check the available modules, if they are smart enough already. If not: I recommend the `stats` module. Advantage over the other solution: No "red errors but ignored" in the output.

```
- name: Check MySQL data directory existence
  stat: path=/var/lib/mysql-slave
  register: mysql_slave_data_dir

- name: Stop MySQL master to copy data directory
  service: name=mysql state=stopped
  sudo: yes 
  when: not mysql_slave_data_dir.stat.exists
```

Answer (score 10):

There are at least two options here.

You can register a variable if the file exists, then [use a when condition](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) to execute the command on the condition that the file doesn't already exist:

```
- command: /usr/bin/test -e {{project_root}}/solr/solr-4.7.0.zip
  register: solr_zip
  ignore_errors: True
- name: Download Solr
  shell: chdir={{project_root}}/solr /usr/bin/wget http://mirror.mel.bkb.net.au/pub/apache/lucene/solr/4.7.0/solr-4.7.0.zip
  when: solr_zip|failed
```

You could also use the [commands module](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html) with the `creates` option:

```
- name: Download Solr
  command: /usr/bin/wget http://mirror.mel.bkb.net.au/pub/apache/lucene/solr/4.7.0/solr-4.7.0.zip chdir={{project_root}}/solr  creates={{project_root}}/solr/solr-4.7.0.zip
```

Comment: Use the `wget -nv` or `wget -q` when downloading big files, otherwise the constant output for the progress bar will result in a memory error in ansible.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html) might be useful

Out of it comes this example:

```
tasks:
  - shell: if [[ -f "/etc/monitrc" ]]; then /bin/true; else /bin/false; fi
    register: result
    ignore_errors: True

  - command: /bin/something
    when: result|failed

  - command: /bin/something_else
    when: result|success

  - command: /bin/still/something_else
    when: result|skipped
```

Comment: `if true then return true else return false endif`

Answer (score 4):

So basically you can do this checking by registering a variable from a command and checking its return code. (You can also do this by checking its stdout)

```
- name: playbook
  hosts: all
  user: <your-user>

  vars:
    project_root: /usr/local

  tasks:

    - name: Check if the solr zip exists.
      command: /usr/bin/test -e {{project_root}}/solr/solr-4.7.0.zip
      ignore_errors: True
      register: solr_exists

    - name: Download Solr
      shell: chdir={{project_root}}/solr wget http://mirror.mel.bkb.net.au/pub/apache/lucene/solr/4.7.0/solr-4.7.0.zip
      when: solr_exists.rc != 0
```

This basically says that if the `/usr/bin/test -e {{project_root}}/solr/solr-4.7.0.zip` command returns a code that is not 0, meaning it doesn't exist then execute the task `Download Solr`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

my favourite is to only download the file if it is *newer* than the local file (which includes when the local file does not exist)

the `-N` option with wget does this: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping-Usage.html .

sadly, i don't think there is an equivalent feature in `get_url`

so a very small change:

`- name: Download Solr
    shell: chdir={{project_root}}/solr wget -N http://<SNIPPED>/solr-4.7.0.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `creates` argument

```
- name: Download Solr
  shell: creates={{working_directory}}/solr/solr-4.7.0.zip chdir={{working_directory}}/solr wget http://mirror.mel.bkb.net.au/pub/apache/lucene/solr/4.7.0/solr-4.7.0.zip
```

Comment: This was already said in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22470088/2795592

Comment: And also in a comment at the original question, but it needed more visibility